# Login validation using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, asp.net

Asp login using JavaScript

It is not working and I don't know why? `function check()`

```js
<script>
            function check() {
                var jname, jpass, jpre_pass, jmail;
                jname = document.getElementById("name").value;
                jpass = document.getElementById("pass").value;
                jpre_pass = document.getElementById("pre_pass").value;
                jmail = document.getElementById("mail").value;
                var emailExp = /^([a-zA-Z0-9_\.\-])+\@(([a-zA-Z0-9\-])+\.)+([com\co\.\in])+$/; 
                if (isNan(jname)) {
                    document.getElementById("cname").innerHTML = "enter the name first";
                    document.getElementById("lcheck").innerHTML = "false";
                }
                if (isNan(jpass)) {
                    document.getElementById("cpas").innerHTML = "enter the password ";
                    document.getElementById("lcheck").innerHTML = "false";
                }
                if (isNan(jpre_pass)) {
                    document.getElementById("cpre_pass").innerHTML = "enter the  pre_pass";
                    document.getElementById("lcheck").innerHTML = "false";
                } else if (jpre_pass != jpass) {
                    document.getElementById("cpre_pass").innerHTML = "passwords not matches";
                    document.getElementById("lcheck").innerHTML = "false";
                }
                if (isNan(jmail)) {
                    document.getElementById("cmail").innerHTML = "enter the mail";
                    document.getElementById("lcheck").innerHTML = "false";
                }else if(jmail.match(emailExp))
                {
                    document.getElementById("cmail").innerHTML = "invalid mail";
                    document.getElementById("lcheck").innerHTML = "false";
                }
            }
        </script>
```

```html
<div>
            <asp:TextBox ID="name" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
            <p id="cname"></p>
            <asp:TextBox ID="pass" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
            <p id="cpass"></p>
            <asp:TextBox ID="pre_pass" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
            <p id="cpre_pass"></p>
            <asp:TextBox ID="mail" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
            <p id="cmail"></p>
            <asp:Label ID="lcheck" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>
            <asp:Button ID="btn" runat="server" Text="submit" OnClientClick="check()"/>
            
        </div>
```

Comment: What is not working?

Comment: validation it doesn't work

Comment: I understand that it doesn't work; what does it do and what messages or error codes/documentation are you getting?  console.log?

Comment: doesn't do any thing it just post-back and clear textboxs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can check value it self without `isNan`. Here is it:

```
function check() {
    var jname, jpass, jpre_pass, jmail;
    jname = document.getElementById("name").value;
    jpass = document.getElementById("pass").value;
    jpre_pass = document.getElementById("pre_pass").value;
    jmail = document.getElementById("mail").value;
    var emailExp = /^([a-zA-Z0-9_\.\-])+\@(([a-zA-Z0-9\-])+\.)+([com\co\.\in])+$/; 
    var isValid = true;
    if (!jname) {
        document.getElementById("cname").innerHTML = "enter the name first";
        document.getElementById("lcheck").innerHTML = "false";
        isValid = false;
    }
    if (!jpass) {
        document.getElementById("cpas").innerHTML = "enter the password ";
        document.getElementById("lcheck").innerHTML = "false";
        isValid = false;
    }
    if (!jpre_pass) {
        document.getElementById("cpre_pass").innerHTML = "enter the  pre_pass";
        document.getElementById("lcheck").innerHTML = "false";
        isValid = false;
    } else if (jpre_pass != jpass) {
        document.getElementById("cpre_pass").innerHTML = "passwords not matches";
        document.getElementById("lcheck").innerHTML = "false";
        isValid = false;
    }
    if (!jmail) {
        document.getElementById("cmail").innerHTML = "enter the mail";
        document.getElementById("lcheck").innerHTML = "false";
        isValid = false;
    } else if(jmail.match(emailExp))
    {
        document.getElementById("cmail").innerHTML = "invalid mail";
        document.getElementById("lcheck").innerHTML = "false";
        isValid = false;
    }

    return isValid;
}
```

You have to make sure that the `id` names are exists in the rendered page(in the browser). As I know server controls id names will be changed after rendered page.

before all, you need to attach event to `onsubmit`. Here it is:

```
document.forms[0].attachEvent("onsubmit", check);
```

Comment: thank you it works but still make post back and clear what inside <p>

Comment: because `<p>` element is filled on the client side, and `<p>` is not server element. You have to validate your `form` in the client side and after this send to server. You may attach your `check()` method to on `onsubmit` method of `form` element. and control validation with returns `true` of `false` from the 'check()' method.

Comment: i understand you but don't know how to do it could you show me how ?

Comment: https://scontent-cdg.xx.fbcdn.net/hphotos-xpa1/v/t1.0-9/10968310_446896252131597_596152708567828334_n.jpg?oh=5c3a94f948afd0efea48fb8d7b67418d&oe=55501581

there is an error i take a screen shot for you check it

Comment: you need to set this `document.forms[0].attachEvent("onsubmit", check);` before `check` method.

Comment: it works a little syntax error from email formula i will find it thanks very much i really appreciate your effort

Answer (score 0):

First, `isNaN` checks if a particular value is `NaN`. Because you're not parsing any of the input into a number, there's no way that any of those if statements will evaluate to true. You probably want to check that those values are not empty strings.

Second, once you get your validation if-statements working, if you want to prevent a post back you'll need to call event.preventDefault().

You'll need to pass the event object to your `check()` function and call `preventDefault` if any of your validation statements evaluate to false.

For example:

```
function clickHandler(event) {
    check(event);
}

function check (event)
    ...validation

    if (!valid) event.preventDefault();
}
```

Comment: i didn't understand did you mean that i put it in OnClick="clickHandler" or what ?

Comment: On you're .aspx page, you'll need to add some javascript that assigns an event handler to the form's submit event (probably a button click). The OnClick attribute is for assigning a server side event handler that gets called after the postback. Here's a link to jQuery documentation: http://jqfundamentals.com/chapter/events